# vue.js with laravel : Failed to resolve module specifier "vue". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, laravel-blade, laravel-vue

while integrating vue.js in laravel blade file facing this error

> "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vue".
> Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"."

the code is

```
// Import Vue.js
    import Vue from 'vue';
    
    // Import your Vue components
    import ExampleComponent from './components/ExampleComponent.vue';
    
    // Register Vue components
    Vue.component('example-component', ExampleComponent);
    
    // Create Vue instance
    const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
    });
    
    vue is installed properly but still.
    
    npm install vue
    
    npm install -g @vue/cli
    
     npm install @vue/cli --save-dev
```